# LinqToSQL not updating database

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, visual-studio-2010

I created a database and dbml in visual studio 2010 using its wizards. Everything was working fine until i checked the tables data (also in visual studio server explorer) and none of my updates were there.

```
using (var context = new CenasDataContext())
{
    context.Log = Console.Out;
    context.Cenas.InsertOnSubmit(new Cena() { id = 1});
    context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

This is the code i am using to update my database. At this point my database has one table with one field (PK) named ID.

> **INSERT INTO [dbo].Cenas VALUES (@p0)
>   -- @p0: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [1]
>   -- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build:
>   4.0.30319.1**

This is LOG from the execution (printed the context log into the console).

The problem i'm having is that these updates are not persistent in the database. I mean that when i query my database (visual studio server explorer -> new query) i see the table is empty, every time.

I am using a SQL Server database file (.mdf).

**EDIT (1):** Immediate Window result

```
context.GetChangeSet()
{Inserts: 1, Deletes: 0, Updates: 0}
    Deletes: Count = 0
    Inserts: Count = 1
    Updates: Count = 0
context.GetChangeSet().Inserts
Count = 1
    [0]: {DBTest.Cena}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you construct a `DataContext` without arguments, it will retrieve its connection string from your App.Config or Web.Config file.  Open the one that applies, and verify that it points to the same database.

Comment: I guess you were right. 

The problem was that the wizard to created LinqToSql file (dbml) with the DataContext reading the Settings.settings file and not the App.config. So i was sure it was accessing the right database but it wasn't. I don't even know what it was doing <<

Note to self: don't trust the wizards.

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint on context.SubmitChanges(); and in your immediate window in VS, do:

```
context.GetChangeSet();
```

There is an inserts property and it should have one record.  That will help tell if its queuing up an insert.

HTH.